# Extender Resource Controllers

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-rotas

Estou fazendo o que quero de uma forma e estou buscando alternativas ou melhores formas de fazer.
Estou usando Resource Controllers na minha aplicação. Também estou usando o softdelete em vários models, então minhas rotas estão assim:

```php
Route::get('users/deleted', array('uses' => 'UserController@trash'));
Route::put('users/{id}/restore', array('uses' => 'UserController@restore'));
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

A primeira rota é para exibir os que foram deletados.
A segunda permite que eu restaure estes elementos deletados.
A terceira mapeia os métodos tradicionais (create, edit, update etc).

O que acontece é que como eu tenho vários controllers que funcionam exatamente da mesma forma, gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de dizer ao laravel que quando eu tenho um Resource Controller, os métodos restore e trash funcionam nas requests nos padrões acima.

É possível? Ou dá para fazer de uma forma melhor que a que estou fazendo?

Answer (score 1):

> Com base neste post do [forum do Laravel](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=26843) você pode resolver isso.

```php
class MyRouter extends \Laravel\Routing\Router {}
```

> app/config/app.php

```
'aliases'   => array( 
//--//
Route'  => 'MyRoute'
//--//
);
```

> Não testei a solução para sabe se funciona 100%, mas acredito que você poderá criar todos os métodos que deseja assim.